# How accurate is Google's libphonenumber?

Tags: libphonenumber

I'm wanting to incorporate Google's libphonenumber library into a CRM solution that I'm working on, to identify things such as:

- Whether a phone number is mobile or landline
- Geo-location of the number

I've done some searching online, and can't seem to find anything discussing what algorithms the library is using to determine this information, and how reliable those methods are.

Is there any such documentation (ie, details of the these algorithms and their respective reliability)? Or really, anything to help me understand what happens under-the-covers for this library?

Comment: Hi Ryan, I'm looking at libphonenumber myself at the moment,But i'am at a lose on how to integrate it into Dynamic CRM.Im very new to CRM and javascript are there any tutorials or examples for intergrating it? Thanks Alan

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's an [Open Source library](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fjava%2Flibphonenumber%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fi18n%2Fphonenumbers), so you can see *exactly* how it works :)

```
svn checkout http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/source/checkout
```

I've had a quick look at the source, and it seems to work by testing the phone number with a series of regular expressions. [Big regex files](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/source/browse/trunk/java/#java%2Flibphonenumber%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fi18n%2Fphonenumbers%2Fdata) are defined for various countries, which define the regular expressions that will tell you the type of phone number (for example, in the UK, all mobiles start with "07", so there will be a regex based on that).

Comment: You were asking for (and I quote) "details of the algorithms". Nothing could be more detailed than the source. The source also provides the very best documentation (particularly since their javadocs are so poor). So yes, I think reading the source (of which there are about 5 files of real interest) is exactly what you should do, given the question you asked.

Comment: Does it make any calls out to their servers?